# SQL Server Joining Similar Yet Dissimilar Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, full-outer-join

I have two tables of data that I need to join into a single table.  `UNION ALL` doesn't work because I need to have a single row (`SN`) with all associated info and not duplicate `SN`s.  Examples of the two tables and the expected result are below.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
Table 1
SN  Reading
 1. 12
 2. 14
 3. 12
 4. 15
 5. 11

Table 2 
SN  Reading
 1. 75 
 2. 74
 4. 74
 5. 74
 6. 75
```

Joined Table (1 and 2)

```
SN  R1    R2
 1. 12    75
 2. 14    74
 3. 12
 4. 15    74
 5. 11    74
 6.       75
```

Comment: Look at a `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FULL JOIN` to join tables in the desired way and `COALESCE` to get first non-null  `SN` from both tables :

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.SN, t2.SN)
     , t1.R1
     , t2.R2 
FROM table1 t1 FULL JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.SN = t2.SN
```